# Take tag contents from string without jquery

Tags: javascript

I have **string** like:

```js
string = `<div>
   <div>This is not to be used</div>
   <div id="takeThis">
    <p>Some content</p>
    <div>Some more content<div>
    ...
   </div>
   <div>Also not relevant
   </div>
 </div>`
  
// TODO get the content 'Some content' and 'Some more content'
```

In plain `JS` I want to extract `id="takeThis"` contents as string.

I tried:

1. `RegExp`like: `<div\sid=\"takeThis\">([\s\S]*)<\/div>` - problem is that it takes first or last occurance of `</div>` - not div node as a whole
2. `const parser = new DOMParser(); const doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');` `DOMParser` seems to strip `id` attribute.

Edit: 
I have string - not Html

I see that my second way is working but not in all cases. I have to investigate.

Comment: [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) ?

Comment: never use regex on html!

Comment: @Cid it's not html - it's string. If I create `const div = document.createElement('div'); div.innerHTML = str;` there is no `getElementById` method in `div`.

Comment: document.getElementById('takeThis').innerText;

Comment: @HerrSerker Did a rollback on your change since the code was badly formatted and the snippet doesn't add anything since the OP uses it as a string. Please read a post first before editing it.

Comment: @MarkBaijens I have read it, but didn't understand the real intention

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) on created `div`

> Returns the first element that is a descendant of the element on which it is invoked that matches the specified group of selectors.

```js
var str = `<div>
  <div>First
  </div>
  <div id="takeThis">
      <p>sad</p>
      <div> sd asd asda sd asdd dsfsdf sdf<div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>`

const div = document.createElement('div'); 
div.innerHTML = str;

console.log(div.querySelector('#takeThis').textContent)
```

Comment: It worked with `innerHTML` insead of `textContent`. Have to read difference. Thanks

Comment: @piernik `textContent` will return `text` whereas `innerHTML` will return `HTML`

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="takeThis">
    <p>sad</p>
    <div>
        <div>hello</div>
        sd asd asda sd asdd dsfsdf sdf
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

**To get the text content of an element by ID:**

```
const takeThis = document.getElementById('takeThis').textContent;
```

**To get the text content of an element by using a generic query selector:**

```
const takeThis = document.querySelector('#takeThis').textContent;
```

This will give you the text content of all the nested content regardless of multiple levels of nesting.

If you want to get the HTML content, you can use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`.

Answer (score 0):

Code here for the fans of Regex:

```js
let string = `<div>
   <div>This is not to be used</div>
   <div id="takeThis">
    <p>Some content</p>
    <div>Some more content</div>
          <p> A good content </p>
    <div class="test1">Test more</div>
    <p class="abc" id="abcp">Good content</p>
   </div>
   <div>Also not relevant
   </div>
 </div>`;
  
// TODO get the content 'Some content' and 'Some more content'
let regex = /<div id="takeThis">((((.|\n)*?)<div .*?>(.|\n)*?(<\/div>)((.|\n)*?))*)<\/div>/i;
string.replace(regex, function(match){
    // console.log(match);
    console.log(match.replace(/\s*<\w.*?>\s*/g,'').replace(/\s*<\/.*?>\s*/g,'\n'));
});
```